# How are activities involving toy blocks linked the development of intelligence in children?

Tags: intelligence, developmental-psychology, problem-solving, motor, communication

I'm looking for a peer reviewed article that links the development of intelligence to any form of block building activities.

For example a child playing with wooden blocks can improve their sensory-motor and communication skills while learning to solve problems.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Google scholar! It gives me this, for example: Diezmann, Carmel M and Watters, James J (2000) Identifying and supporting spatial
intelligence in young children.. Contemporary Issues in Early Childhood 1(3):299-
313.

Comment: Thank you Ana but it is not really pertaining to blocks as such.  I'm looking for a more human focused version of something like this: [link](http://web.media.mit.edu/~push/StThomas-AIMag.pdf)

Comment: Then I don't think I can help. There is a reference to an old study that involves blocks in there though (someone and Burton, 1984).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I consider to be the best reference [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0935989765)

Hirsch, E. S. (1996). The block book (Third ed.). Washington, DC: National Association for the Education of Young Children.

It's certainly going in the thesis after glancing through it.  Thought posting it here might helps others too.